# (Literature) Diffusion Coefficient Of Potassium Permanganate

Tags: physical-chemistry

I'm doing a practical report on an experiment I had this week where I studied the diffusion coefficient of KMnO<sub>4</sub> in water by the free boundary method. I have calculated the diffusion coefficient of potassium permanganate using this method, but now I need to compare this calculated value against the literature diffusion coefficient value of KMnO<sub>4</sub>. I've looked in my textbook and looked through a bunch of websites, but I just can't seem to find this value. If anyone can help me find this value or could tell me what it is, it would be very much appreciated.

Edit: No need to answer this question anymore since I spoke to my Scientific Officer and she said I should leave out the comparison of this literature value with the measured one. I'll leave this question open for answering though since someone might run into the same problem as I have in the future.